# display numbered div list in two uneven columns

Tags: html, css, position

[link to website][1]

I have a problem with alignment of the boxes with the text. They all have  different sizes and should be organised in 2 columns without margin.

I have used following code:
css

```
.article_advices_ed6a5a_left{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ed6a5a;
}

.article_advices_f4f1bb_left{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f4f1bb;
}

.article_advices_9bc1bc_left{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #9bc1bc;
}

.article_advices_5ca4a9_left{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #5ca4a9;
}

.article_advices_e6ebe0_left{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #e6ebe0;
}
```

html

```
<div class="article_advices_ed6a5a_left">
<h4>1. Следуй за белым графиком</h4>

Зная список участников и гостей, заранее составляй расписание встреч на выставке. Ты не сможешь окупить затраты на выставку, надеясь на трафик случайных посетителей. Ставь встречи с клиентами, готовыми к покупке или сотрудничеству, в то же время, что и с «холодными» клиентами. Это создаст о компании позитивное впечатление. И ты удивишься, как «горячие» клиенты смогут «продавать» за тебя.
</div>

<div class="article_advices_f4f1bb_left">
<h4>2. Рассылай всё равно</h4>

Поговаривают, что рассылка партнерам и клиентам анонса выставки по мэйлу уже не эффективна. Верно, но рассылай приглашения прийти к тебе на стенд, несмотря ни на что. Это знак внимания, плюс — всегда можно придумать вескую причину заглянуть к тебе. Например, скидку или подарок.
</div>

<div class="article_advices_9bc1bc_left">
<h4>3. Планируй утром</h4>

Если выставка идет несколько дней, проводи планерки с коллегами по стенду каждое утро. Напоминай роли и функции всей команде. А накануне выставки настрой людей на четкую цель: озвучь точный план продаж, контактов, встреч.
</div>


<div class="article_advices_5ca4a9_left">
<h4>4. Не трать время прессы зря</h4>
Поймать прессу сложно, поэтому заранее пригласи на стенд журналистов. Живое общение — основа взаимного доверия, а результат — лояльное отношение к компании и частое упоминание в публикациях. Организуй встречу так, чтобы у журналиста не осталось ощущения, что он потратил время впустую. Подготовь неформальную презентацию продукта, расскажи о нем интересно: журналист должен понять, чем твой продукт может быть полезен лично ему. Не забудь в финале встречи закрепить пройденное — вручи пресс-релиз, в котором письменно зафиксированы все озвученные тезисы. Будет здорово, если релиз в электронном виде будет на флэшке с логотипом компании. Не забудь записать на флэшку логотип и, если есть, фотографии. 
</div>



<div class="article_advices_ed6a5a_left">
<h4>5. Используй гид </h4>

Убедись, что организатор выставки включил описание твоей компании/продукта в печатный или электронный гид по выставке, пресс-релиз и пост-релиз. 
</div>


<div class="article_advices_f4f1bb_left">
<h4>6. Держи буклеты при себе</h4>

Не покупай место в пресс-стойке для своих буклетов. Весь раздаточный материал должен находиться у тебя на стенде: это дешевле, а главное — ты всегда будешь знать, кто получил буклет.
</div>



<div class="article_advices_9bc1bc_left">
<h4>7. Устрой трапезу</h4>
Сытая аудитория — лояльная аудитория. Неформальное общение с клиентами, партнерами или прессой в формате завтрака или ланча — идеальный вариант презентации. Только гостей надо подбирать тщательно и ориентироваться на их цели и мотивацию. На то и существует таргетирование и директ-маркетинг. Особенно удачно такой вариант презентации срабатывает с прессой. А сэкономить на организации завтрака-ланча можно, привлекая спонсоров. 
</div>




<div class="article_advices_5ca4a9_left">
<h4>8. Пакет — каждому</h4>

Если ты считаешь, что затраты на трапезу того не стоят, то дешевле, а иногда и эффективней, устроить короткую конференцию с хорошо таргетированной аудиторией. Не забудь положить на каждый стул папку с пресс-релизом, брошюрой или журналом. А лучше — брендированный пакет со всей информацией и небольшим сувениром от компании. Главное, чтобы конференция не длилась больше 30 минут, иначе внимание аудитории будет потеряно.
</div>



<div class="article_advices_e6ebe0_left">
<h4>9. Управляй стендом</h4>

Специально обученный человек, а не инженер или замдиректора, должен всегда присутствовать на стенде. Только маркетолог сможет оценить эффективность работу стенда и сориентироваться в ситуации, чтобы повысить профит от выставки. Менеджеры на стенде всегда ждут возможности «напасть» на посетителя, далеко не каждый менеджер способен заманить человека на стенд приятной беседой, а не нарочитой попыткой продажи. 
</div>



<div class="article_advices_ed6a5a_left">
<h4>10. Сортируй трафик</h4>

Помни простую схему эффективной работы: маркетолог приглашает гостя на стенд, менеджер анализирует гостя и выясняет потребности, иногда анкетирует, и только после этого гость идет к менеджеру по продажам и тот проводит с гостем столько времени, сколько потребуется. 
</div>


<div class="article_advices_f4f1bb_left">
<h4>11. Организуй доставку</h4>

Отличная возможность познакомить всех участников выставки со своей компанией — устроить им доставку утренней газеты в брендированном конверте, например. Но это сработает, если все участники живут в одном отеле. Иначе — заранее напечатай гид по местным ресторанам «по версии компании» и раздай прямо на выставке. Благодарности не избежать. 
</div>


<div class="article_advices_9bc1bc_left">
<h4>12. Не трать на безделушки</h4>

Часто раздаточный материал — пустая трата. За ним охотятся «выставочные коллекционеры», собирающие брендированные ручки и прочую ерунду. Реальные клиенты хотят от тебя решения их задач, а не брелок. Но если уж ты решил подготовить немного сувениров, пусть они будут релевантны продукту. Если ты представляешь приморский отель, вручай гостям пляжное полотенце, а не блокнот или наклейку на авто. 
</div>

<div class="article_advices_5ca4a9_left">
<h4>13. Отказывай красиво</h4>

Не раздавай буклеты и сувениры кому попало. Но прямо не отказывай. Скажи, что ты вышлешь буклет по почте, чтобы сейчас не пришлось таскать тяжести. Настаивай на своем. В лучшем случае ты получишь контакты посетителя и сможешь его идентифицировать, в худшем — человек поймет, что презент ему не достанется и уйдет с миром. 
</div>

<div class="article_advices_e6ebe0_left">
<h4>14. Движение — жизнь</h4>

Активнее всего гости выставок реагируют на движение. Если у тебя на стенде есть движущийся предмет, механизм, робот или фонтан — это половина успеха. Важно, чтобы нечто движущееся было релевантно продукту. Нет смысла ставить фонтан на стенд бумажной фабрики, пусть это будет гигантское оригами.
</div>
```

As the result it shows random vertical spaces between boxes. This disappears if I'm adding `height:500px`, but then all boxes are the same size which is can not be solution in my case.

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDjqJ.png)

[my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tqAr.png)

Comment: Please provide your html code.

Comment: Please share your HTML code also.

Comment: where is your HTML code??

Comment: sorry, just added it

Comment: @O.Telegin what vertical spaces?? I am not getting any. can you please elaborate little

Comment: added link to the page and image with the problem

Comment: @O.Telegin set`min-height` for div

Comment: @Navy did not help

Comment: @O.Telegin in your case  set `min-height: 540px;` for each `div` and remove `max-height:100%;`

Comment: @Navy then they all will be the same size, in my case i need other result. Just added the image with the result which I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS3 layout mode **flexbox**

- wrap your <div>s with a <div class="container">
- add CSS:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 1750px;  // use a size necessary to split text into two columns
}
```

- there's no need for the `float: left` property. Remove them.
- to best achieve the expected result, run the JavaScript filter below to sort your items in **odds column** and **evens column**.

```js
// grabbing odd articles
var articlesLeft = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='article_advices_']:nth-child(odd)");
// grabbing even articles
var articlesRight = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='article_advices_']:nth-child(even)");
console.log(articlesLeft, articlesRight);
// clearing article nodes from container
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
container.innerHTML = "";
// appending all odd articles then appending even articles
articlesLeft.forEach(function(article) {
    container.appendChild(article);
});
articlesRight.forEach(function(article) {
    container.appendChild(article);
});
```

here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/hcv2ps9r/1/

--
Also:

- you could use: `flex-direction: row` but it would need `stretch`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: very close. now there are 3 boxes in each column and it is going far away to the right, which destroys the structure. Is it possible to make only 2 columns which will fit to max-width of the page ?

Comment: ok good, when I changed the height to 4000px, then I got 2 columns, but now the structure of the boxes a bit wrong. In the left column it goes the boxes from 1 to 14 and in right column from 14 to 26. It would be great if you have a solution how to make in the left column odd boxes and in the right even  
....

Comment: I'm testing my code https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/hcv2ps9r/ but let's see where yours differ. (notice I deleted previous solution, for second code)

Comment: your test link now the boxes are the same size, but I really should make them keep their own size. So the first code was closer I think

Comment: I added the Javascript filter. also: remember to update your `.container's height` so only odd numbers appear on the left

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you're trying to do all boxes need to be the same minimum height, it worked for me making all the boxes the height of the largest one which was

```
min-height: 400px;
height: auto;
```

And removing

```
max-height:100%;
```

There may be other ways to do this but this is certainly one.

Comment: Then they will be all the same size, but in my case I don't need it. I should keep their original hight.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like: 
Wrap a new div

```
.article-wrapper{
    display: table;
}

.article_advices_ed6a5a_left,

.article_advices_f4f1bb_left,

.article_advices_9bc1bc_left /* ... so on add all your div class*/{

    display: table-cell;
}
```

OR you may also refer:

https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403

Comment: Then they will be all the same size, but in my case I don't need it. I should keep their original hight